# Can a list item point to the column value in another list?

Tags: list, list-view

Is it possible with SharePoint 2010 to have a column in one list point to the value of the column in another list? So List A's Column1 will show the value of List B's Column3 for a specific item. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define List A's column1 as "lookup" field of List B's column3.

Answer (score 5):

if I understand correctly you should use [Lookup Field](http://phase2.com/blog/?p=101).

Comment: The trouble with answers that have a link and no content is that ... well, you can guess the rest.

Answer (score 3):

This functionality is fairly easy to use when adding a Lookup field in a list, but you can do a heck of a lot more programatically, see here for an example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798514.aspx